# Is it possible to make screen videos on a unrooted device? The device is Sony Xperia m2 aqua

Tags: sony-xperia

Recently I want to record some screen videos like to show when bugs happen and e.t.c.Is it possible on a unrooted Sony xperia m2 aqua?If yes how?

Comment: Are you on lollipop? If so, any screen recording app should work without root (tested that on a note 4). If not, you won't need to wait forever for that update. See [here](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2015/06/04/android-5-0-lollipop-rolls-for-the-xperia-z-series-android-5-1-coming-for-xperia-m2-and-xperia-m2-aqua/)

Comment: No I am on kitkat.Sony haven't released the 5.1 yet and I don't want to break some of the options.

Comment: Oh. Well thats a shame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, as Sony Xperia M2 and M2 Aqua have received Lollipop 5.1.1 update, you can start recording your screen with the help of screen recorder apps such as [Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nll.screenrecorder&hl=en) by NLL.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your device [originally came](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_m2_aqua-6582.php) with Android KitKat. You can try a command line method here. `screenrecord` binary does the screen recording. Its maximum recording duration is 180 seconds. In Kitkat, its usages goes by:

```
Usage: screenrecord [options] 

Records the device's display to a .mp4 file.

Options:
--size WIDTHxHEIGHT
    Set the video size, e.g. "1280x720".  Default is the device's main
    display resolution (if supported), 1280x720 if not.  For best results,
    use a size supported by the AVC encoder.
--bit-rate RATE
    Set the video bit rate, in megabits per second.  Default 4Mbps.
--time-limit TIME
    Set the maximum recording time, in seconds.  Default / maximum is 180.
--rotate
    Rotate the output 90 degrees.
--verbose
    Display interesting information on stdout.
--help
    Show this message.
```

In Lollipop, a parameter `bugreport` is also added:

```
--bugreport
    Add additional information, such as a timestamp overlay, that is helpful
    in videos captured to illustrate bugs.
```

An example to record screen using in-built screen recorder (you would need [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) setup in PC and USB debugging enabled in the device),

```
adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 8000000  /sdcard/test.mp4
```

That command will save the screen recording in a file `test.mp4` located under `/sdcard`. Change the bitrate as per your needs, or try an app for GUI.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Sony phones, you can hold the power button and it gives you an option to record the screen/take a screenshot. Otherwise, use [AZ Screen Recorder - No Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hecorat.screenrecorder.free) app.

Comment: Please link the app and also elaborate on the options available written you press the power button and mention the model as well

Comment: You might want to mention that the app you linked requires Android 5.0. and above while OP is [currently running Android KitKat](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120626/is-it-possible-to-make-screen-videos-on-a-unrooted-device-the-device-is-sony-xp/136481#comment149102_120626).