# Is there any way to record android screen in android 4.2.2 without rooting and PC?

Tags: screencast

I want to record my android mobile's screen as a video. I tried many apps from play store but they didn't work with me. My device android version is jelly bean(4.2.2) and it is not rooted. So how can I record my screen without root?

Comment: I tried "Mobizen", "Easy screen recorder", "recordable". You can find them in play store. I am using Micromax a089.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Best App I have found for recording your phone screen: [Shou](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.shou.android&hl=en). It requires rooted Android version 4.1 and up. Also, works without rooting your device.

Other applications that you can try [Kamcord](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kamcord.app&hl=en) (Android 5.0+), etc.

Comment: From the description of Shou: "*ROOT your Android 4.1+ (Jelly Bean, KitKat) devices to broadcast or record your screen*". So, on which Android version did you test it without root access? Can you provide a screenshot of your Android version and another screenshot depicting that Shou is recording screen in your Android version without root access?

Answer (score 0):

No. As strange as it may seem, there is no way to record your screen without root on android before 5.0. If possible you should upgrade to a newer version, but if that is not possible you have to root. Also it is possible that the apps you downloaded from Google Play Store require root.

Comment: You can use `screenrecord` using adb. Doesn't require root access. See [Is it possible to make screen videos on a unrooted device? The device is Sony Xperia m2 aqua](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/120629)